# DataTables line-height control

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatables

Is it possible to control the line height for a `tr` either through a DataTables setting or through CSS?  I've tried various things, but nothing seems to alter the `line-height`.

[image: line-height]

> Table CSS

```
.table tbody tr:hover td, .table tbody tr:hover th {
    background: rgba(36, 198, 213, 0.3);
    opacity: 0.5;
    color: #000;
}

.table tbody {
  font-size: 15px;
}

.dataTable tbody tr {
    line-height: 20px !important;
    height: 40px;
}

.dataTables_paginate a {
    background: #ff0000;
}

.dataTables_wrapper {
    position: relative;
    clear: both;
    zoom: 1;
    /* Feeling sorry for IE */
}

.dataTables_processing {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 250px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-left: -125px;
    margin-top: -15px;
    padding: 14px 0 2px 0;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    text-align: center;
    color: #999;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: white;
}

.dataTables_length {
    width: 40%;
    float: left;
}

.dataTables_filter {
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
}

.dataTables_info {
    width: 60%;
    float: left;
}

.dataTables_paginate {
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#ignored_device_table").DataTable( {
    order: [[ 0, "asc"]],
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: ['copy','excel', 'pdf','csv','print']
  });
});
```

```html
<!-- page content -->
<div class="right_col" role="main">
  <div class="">
    <!-- host data table -->
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="x_panel">
          <div class="x_title">
            <h2>Ignored Devices
              <small>By Date</small>
            </h2>
            <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
              <li>
                <a class="collapse-link">
                  <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                  <i class="fa fa-wrench" role="menu"></i>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a class="close-link">
                  <i class="fa fa-close"></i>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
          </div>

          <div class="x_content">
            <div class="table-responsive">
              <table id="ignored_device_table" class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Date </th>
                    <th>Hostname </th>
                    <th>IP Address </th>
                    <th>Name </th>
                    <th>Reason </th>
                    <th>Expiration </th>
                    <th><span class="nobr">Action</span></th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>05/06/16</td>
                    <td>DB-01</td>
                    <td>192.168.1.100</td>
                    <td>Jimmy Smith</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque id iaculis massa. Mauris libero augue, bibendum ut efficitur a, imperdiet vel nisl. Curabitur ut blandit velit. Nulla tincidunt leo convallis risus bibendum, pulvinar bibendum lectus maximus. Vivamus convallis mi vel mollis sollicitudin. </td>
                    <td>06/06/16</td>
                    <td><a href="#">Restore</a>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>05/02/16</td>
                    <td>DB-02</td>
                    <td>192.168.1.101</td>
                    <td>Jimmy Smith</td>
                    <td>This host is under version control through the IS department and is scheduled to be updated next quarter.</td>
                    <td>06/02/16</td>
                    <td><a href="#">Restore</a>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>04/06/16</td>
                    <td>WEB-01</td>
                    <td>192.168.1.102</td>
                    <td>Jimmy Smith</td>
                    <td>This host is under version control through the IS department and is scheduled to be updated next quarter.</td>
                    <td>05/06/16</td>
                    <td><a href="#">Restore</a>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>03/06/16</td>
                    <td>WEB-02</td>
                    <td>192.168.1.103</td>
                    <td>Jimmy Smith</td>
                    <td>This host is under version control through the IS department and is scheduled to be updated next quarter.</td>
                    <td>04/06/16</td>
                    <td><a href="#">Restore</a>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>02/22/16</td>
                    <td>Firewall</td>
                    <td>192.168.1.104</td>
                    <td>Jimmy Smith</td>
                    <td>This host is under version control through the IS department and is scheduled to be updated next quarter.</td>
                    <td>03/22/16</td>
                    <td><a href="#">Restore</a>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**
-------

Look for th `id` you gave to the table in console.
You'll find `tr` in the near decendants.

Scripting would like like this:

```
$("#ignored_device_table").find("tr").css({"height":"20px"});
```

In your CSS file, you could try (I never did so, can't put my hand in fire):

```
#ignored_device_table tbody tr{
    height:20px !important;
}
```

To play with to whole frame dimentions of the table, You have to deal with the `wrapper`. That is what mixed me up my first fast answer.

---------------
**First answer**
Look for the `id` generated by DataTable to wrap the table.

It **IS** made from the `id` you provided in your HTML as a table id.
Like if your table was named by this id `cert`:

The generated wrapper would be : `cert_wrapper`.
You can find this by inspecting in the console.

Then you can script based on this... Something like:

```
$("#cert_wrapper tr").css({"height":"20px"});
```

You will be able to catch general `tr`, `td`, ect. But not a specific one, since Datable do not generate anything like a rowID or cellID.

Be sure to include those future scripts in an `$(document).ready(function(){});` since the table is generated on client-side.

;)

Comment: Is this because of when the table is generated CSS doesn't work?

Comment: Well You may try... I' can't put my hand in fire on this. I think I always did prevently ;) Your id to search would be : `ignored_device_table_wrapper`.

Comment: Doh!!! I just re-check on my own thing here... Your table `id` is closer to the `tr` than the wrapper. I'll have to edit. But there is a `<tbody>` in between... So you could just do `$("#ignored_device_table").find("tr").css({"height":"20px"});`

Comment: Nope, that didn't change any styling either.

Comment: I just found this.... May interest you : [jQWidgets](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/jqxdatatable/jquery-datatable-styling-and-appearance.htm?search=datatable)

Comment: mmmm. Looks like something else finally. Anyway. I' think I've told you all I know. On my side, I spent hours to set classe to each cells (col number and row number)... It works super! But it's «kind of» custom. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well, after some more tinkering, I had to override the bootstrap styling:

```
.table.dataTable > tbody > tr > td {
  line-height: 2rem !important;
}
```